# Checking the execution of the previous command

Tags: linux, shell-script, echo, oracle-database

I have to perform an operation in a script by connecting to oracle database.I am trying to use expdp command in my shell script to dump the data .

```
Vi ban.sh 

 expdp hr/oracle@oracle table=man   directory =ban dumpfile=man.dmp 
If [ $# -eq 0 ];then
  echo 'fail'
fi
If [ $# -eq 1 ];then
  echo 'pass'
fi
```

In the above script if the table name is given wrong then the oracle expdp fails the status check block in the script is passing through "pass" block but not fail block .How can i handle this situation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `expdp` utility exits with a zero exit status if

> The export or import job completed successfully. No errors are displayed to the output device or recorded in the log file, if there is one. [Ref: [Data Pump Exit Codes](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-34D0DEE7-3530-42DC-BE01-C2588CC73CE5.htm#SUTIL3834)].

Otherwise it will have a non-zero exit status.  This is standard for utilities on Unix. Zero means "Success" and it's also a "true" value in boolean tests.

In your script, you should therefore be able to say

```
if expdp ...other options...; then
   echo 'Success'
else
   echo 'Failure'
fi
```

This means that you got the tests backwards in your code.

If you want to actually display the exit code:

```
expdp ...other options...
code=$?

echo "Exit code is $code"

if [ "$code" -eq 0 ]; then
   echo 'Success'
else
   echo 'Failure'
fi
```

Since `echo` will change `$?`, you will need to save its value to a new variable straight after using `expdp`.

Comment: Thank you sir, I have one more question the codes in the oracle dictionary are the above EX_SUCC 0
EX_FAIL 1
EX_WARN 2
EX_FTL  3   , I gone through the document but how to display these values in the shell script i am a bit confused ,I am trying to echo these values but i am unable to do that in my script after the expdp command ?

Comment: @SanthoshPogaku See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you sir, Now i am clear on the concept .Thanks for your valuable time.